# Google C2DM ACOUNT_MISSING

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am still using Google C2DM instead of GCM. Target devices are CyanogenMod 9 (ICS) and C2DM work well without any creation of Google account in the devices.

But I got the error 'ACCOUT_MISSING' when I run the app an emulator on GB 2.3.3. I found that the message means 'An user must have Google account in the device'. But it does not have any Google account in my ICS devices but it has been working fine. I am so confused about this. Anyone help me please.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I read the C2DM document again and clearly explained about the error.

ACCOUNT_MISSING     There is no Google account on the phone. The application should ask the user to open the account manager and add a Google account. Fix on the device side.

But definitely my testing devices do not have any Google account but C2DM works fine. It has been already almost one year. I cannot understand about this situation.

Comment: If it says it requires an account, this mean that it is only guaranteed to work if you have an account. Anything else is an accident and/or a bug. Add one and be done with it. And migrate to GCM already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is deprecated, you have to use Google Cloud Messaging.And you have to create a google account on your phone.(For Android 4.0, you dont need to create a google account)

Comment: Thanks. Google GCM is good but users have to register Google accounts. This is worry to me because my users are disabled and they don't need it and cannot do it by themselves.